# Using collection_radio_buttons on an object array in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I have an array of objects and i want to be able to display them using a collection_radio_button but it seems like collection_radio_buttons only works on arrays or ActiveRecord Objects. Is there any way to build a collection_radio_button using an array of objects?

This is my array of objects

```
[{:image_url=>"https://assets.braintreegateway.com/payment_method_logo/visa.png?environment=sandbox", :card_type=>"Visa", :last_4=>"0004", :expiration_month=>"10", :expiration_year=>"2019"}, {:image_url=>"https://assets.braintreegateway.com/payment_method_logo/visa.png?environment=sandbox", :card_type=>"Visa", :last_4=>"0004", :expiration_month=>"11", :expiration_year=>"2019"}]
```

This is the code i tried writing but it doesnt work

```
<%= collection_radio_buttons("cards", :card, @payment_methods, item_wrapper_tag: false) do |b|
   b.label { b[:last_4]}
end %>
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The [`collection_radio_buttons`](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_radio_buttons) helper is looking for an array of objects that will respond to the `text_method` input - which is then used for the radio button label generated.

The quick'n'dirty way to get your code working would be to turn your array of hashes into an array of objects that respond to methods named after the keys, IE we can turn them into OpenStructs with:

```rb
@payment_methods = @payment_methods.map { |pm| OpenStruct.new(pm) }
```

Passing this new array of OpenStructs should now print out what you're looking for, without the extra block:

```rb
<%= collection_radio_buttons(:cards, :card, @payment_methods, :last_4, :last_4) %>
```

You may want/need to alter the other inputs - `:card`, `:cards` or `:last_4` - to get the desired result that'll work with the form you're building.

Another option would be to simply build the radio buttons yourself, without using the built in `collection_radio_buttons` helper... something like:

```rb
<% @payment_methods.each do |pm| %>
  <%= radio_button_tag 'cards[card]', pm[:last_4] %>
  <%= label 'cards[card]', pm[:last_4] %>
<% end %>
```